# ImportXML With Line Breaks Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex, importxml

I am using ImportXML to get some data from a website which looks like the following:

```
=ImportXML("https://www.papercall.io/events?cfps-scope=&keywords=uk","//div[@class='panel panel-default']")
```

While it gets the data ok, two of the fields are both headings `<h4>` and the sheet seems to be importing both of these together into one field. Is there a way I can change the formula above to either change the `<h4>` into a `<p>` or just to add a line break after the `<h4>` is closed?

Comment: formula returns #N/A

Comment: Yes because I'm not using the real website. I will edit it.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDr6c.png which cell(s) is the one bothering you and how do you wish it to look like?

Comment: Column A is fine. Column B has a URL and then dates that I would want to be separated. I would want the event date to go into column C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you can regex it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({INDEX(IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.papercall.io/events?cfps-scope=&keywords=uk", 
 "//div[@class='panel panel-default']"),,1), 
 IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.papercall.io/events?cfps-scope=&keywords=uk",
 "//div[@class='panel panel-default']"),,2), "(.*)Event Dates")), 
 IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.papercall.io/events?cfps-scope=&keywords=uk",
 "//div[@class='panel panel-default']"),,2), "(Event Dates.*)"))})
```

[image]

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks!